# Tricky 3 particle distance correlation question for quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, correlation-functions

Three particles are detected/placed/focused at position $x=y=z=t=0$. (So that according to quantum mechanics their momentum/energy are completely unknown).

They are non-interacting Fermions each with mass $m$.

Take a random time in the future. (Any time equally likely to be picked).

Given two particles are distance $< L_1$, what is the probability that the third particle is distance  $< L_2$ from the midpoint of the other two?

Given that if two particles are close together it is likely to be a time close to the $t=0$ and so the other particle is also likely to be close. I believe the probabilities concerned will be non-zero and finite.

How would one work out such a thing?

Comment: You cannot create three identical fermions at the same location??

Comment: @Thomas Not identical. It's a hypothetical. Think of them as 3 massive neutrinos from different families. That's not the important point here. Equally, massive bosons would do just as well.

Comment: But then the fact that they are fermions is irrelevant. Indeed, there are no correlations at all (no interaction and no quantum statistics)

Comment: @Thomas I didn't say anything about interactions.

Comment: All I am saying is that the question is not really tricky. Just the overlap of three uncorrelated Gaussians.

Comment: @Thomas. Well, it's tricky to me!

Comment: I think my point is that the physics is trivial, this is simply about having to do an integral over a bunch of Gaussians. This may indeed be tricky mathematically, if you want it do it analytically (which may or may not be possible), but i can certainly be done numerically.

Comment: Google "Jacbi coordinates" or "hyperspehrical ccordinates for the 3-body problem" for hints on clever coordinate choices for doing these sorts of integrals.